# MailAddress with invalid email

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, delphi, email

We have a business requirement where are required to send emails *from* an invalid address, so as clients are unable to reply.

The invalid address is *PleaseDoNotReply* - note the lack of the domain.

Where this is valid on some of our systems currently written in Delphi, our new system being written in .Net (and using MailAddress) throws this out, as invalid.

This from address is data driven, and once again, it's a business requirement, so has to work this way.

Thoughts?

`New MailAddress("PleaseDoNotReply","PleaseDoNotReply");`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the domain ".invalid" which is reserved for testing purposes.  PleaseDoNotReply@invalid.invalid is guaranteed to be an invalid address. Other reserved domains are listed in [RFC2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#page-2).

Comment: We could try - I'll check, but we're in a system rewrite, with the remit - `has to work as it does now`

Comment: It's not `invalid.com`, but `whatever.invalid`.

Comment: If this is a rewrite, you might want to consider another mail library such as Chilkat.MailMan, which doesn't force you to use MailAddress. It's not free, but low cost.

Comment: @TLama, I'll change my example. I was wondering why invalid.com resolved to an actual domain.

Comment: *invalid.com* is a valid domain name by RFC1035 and *.com* is a valid TLD. I can't see anything that would keep anyone from registering this domain. *.invalid* is **not** a valid TLD (until now), so you cannot register any domain in TLD *.invalid*. So *invalid.com* is not a surprise, it was only a matter of time :o)

Comment: BTW you can actually buy the domain *donotreply.com* :o)

Comment: @TLama Is `.invalid` ok to be used in production? this is from wikipedia: `Any such reserved usage of those TLDs should not occur in production networks that utilize the global domain name system`

Comment: @PageNotFound, no at all. Purpose of those TLDs is primarily for testing and well, if someone will use it in production network, a sender like `PleaseDoNotReply@noone.invalid` may become valid, but the usage of such TLD is against RFC 2606.

Comment: @TLama and there is an huge chance to that email end up in the spam box

Comment: @PageNotFound, yes, there is. Even when you use just `PleaseDoNotReply` as OP attempted to. But that's a consequence of that requirement. I think that because of this, many people use just a footer text like *"this e-mail is generated automatically, do not respond to it"* which doesn't have this risk. I would do the same personally, since a good spam box should filter messages whose claim they are from a different sender than they actually are from.